# How to route all Node A traffic through Node B

Tags: kubernetes

I have 4 nodes 3 Windows and 1 Linux, I simply need to route all traffic from windows nodes though Linux node.

Any inputs how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a thing Kubernetes is involved in. It would be up to your CNI plugin and your overall networking setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is not realted to kubernetes however still if you are for answer in kubernetes you can create gateway with VM. In which all VM traffic will be redirect via another VM.

Here the example of terraform script : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/master/examples/gke-nat-gateway